# Redhat OS upgrade and kernel revision

Tags: redhat

Is it OK to run RedHat 5.8 off the RedHat 5.9 kernel (version 348) ?  This automatically happened when I updated my OS.  Do I need to change it back to the correct kernel version in my /etc/grub.conf file ?

Comment: The updated kernel is the one you should be using.

Answer (score 2):

You should be fine. Red hat subreleases are far more flexible than, say, Solaris U# releases. It isn't uncommon to install off a rev like 5.4, run yum update, and then see the redhat-release file suddenly show that you're at RH 5.8 (in fact, it can be kind of troublesome when you need specific file levels to ensure multiple environments are exactly in sync, or if you tell technicians that you are installing 5.4, they run updates, and suddenly see 5.8). In fact, if you check /etc/redhat-release it may show that your OS is now running 5.9 instead of 5.8.

About the only thing you may have to worry about is if there were any kernel modules built which relied on the 5.8 kernel. The dmesg output should show you if you have any errors. Other than that, soak the environment for a few days and see if there are any problems. If not, enjoy the new kernel!

Comment: The OS version is still at 5.8 (from /etc/redhat-release) because I put the exclude statement in my yum.conf file i.e. exclude=redhat-release-5Server-*